# How to loop a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have matrices of dim `c(,2)` that are stored in a list. I would like to extract all the matrices of the list and plot them on the same graph.

```
x1.list = list(c(12,35),rbind(c(12,45),c(6,51)),c(4,24))

for (i in 1:length(x1.list)) {

v = data.frame(x1.list[[i]])

r <- r + geom_point(data=lol, aes(v$X1, v$X2), color="blue", size=3)

if (nrow(v)>1){r<-r+ geom_path(data=v, aes(v$X1, v$X2), color="blue")}

r <- r +xlab("input 1") + ylab("input2")
}
```

It is supposed to print on the graph all the elements of the list, and also to plot a line that would bind all the points of eacht element of the list. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: what is the pre-defined `r` and how does the data `lol` look like?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to graph all the coordinates across the list elements. Instead of looping, you could row bind the lists before plotting:

```
x1.df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", x1.list))

x1.df
  V1 V2
1 12 35
2 12 45
3  6 51
4  4 24

ggplot(data=x1.df, aes(V1, V2)) +
   geom_line(color="blue", size=3)
```

[image: image plot]

Comment: In fact, I would like to keep the elements of the list distinct because there is this path that goes across every element of each matrix within the list. Then I really need a loop right?

Answer (score 0):

in this way you could save all plots in a pdf file.

```
 pdf(file = "plots.pdf")
lapply(1:length(x1.list),function(i){

  v = data.frame(x1.list[[i]])

  if (ncol(v)>=2&nrow(v)>1){ r <- ggplot(data = v,aes(X1,X2))+geom_point( color="blue", size=3)

  r<-r+ geom_path(color="blue") 

  r +xlab("input 1") + ylab("input2")}
   }
)
dev.off()
```